# Angular - Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 21 in [form.loading_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'=$event]

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular-7 for web portal application. I have a Material Datepicker from which I would like to only get date with no timestamp. Also it should be in this format: dd/mm/yyyy.

my.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, NgZone, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../../shared/services/api.service';
import { TokenService } from '../../shared/services/token.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SnotifyService } from 'ng-snotify';
import swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-client-quotes-landing',
  templateUrl: './client-quotes-landing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-quotes-landing.component.scss']
})
export class ClientQuotesLandingComponent implements OnInit {

  public form = {
    first_name : null,
    last_name : null,
    email : null,
    phone : null,
    address : null,
    business_name : null,
    truck_required : null,
    truck_type : null,
    quote_origin : null,
    quote_destination : null,
    commodity : null,
    loading_date : null,
    comment : null,
  };

  public error = {
    'first_name' : null,
    'last_name' : null,
    'email' : null,
    'phone' : null,
    'address' : null,
    'business_name' : null,
    'truck_required' : null,
    'truck_type' : null,
    'quote_origin' : null,
    'quote_destination' : null,
    'commodity' : null,
    'loading_date' : null,
    'comment' : null
  };

  constructor(
    private api: ApiService,
    private token: TokenService,
    private router: Router,
    private notify: SnotifyService,
    ) {
     }     

  ngOnInit() {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.notify.clear();
    var header = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    return this.api.post('clientquotelanding', this.form, header).subscribe(
      error => this.errorHandle(error),
    );
  }

  tokenHandler(data){
    this.notify.clear();
    console.log(data);
  }

  errorHandle(error){
    this.notify.clear();
    console.log(error);
    this.error = error.error.errors;
  }

}
```

my.component.html

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <label for="loading_date">Loading Date<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
  <div class="input-group date" style="width: 100%;" >
   <mat-form-field>
     <input matInput [matDatepicker] = "picker" placeholder = "Choose a date" name="loading_date" [(ngModel)]="form.loading_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'" #loading_date="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : loading_date.invalid && ((loading_date.dirty || loading_date.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)}"   required>
     <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for] = "picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
     <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
     </mat-form-field>
     <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="loading_date.invalid && ((loading_date.dirty || loading_date.touched) || clientquoteForm.submitted)">
      <div style="color:red;" *ngIf="loading_date.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Loading Date is required.</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my.component.html, I tried to use built-in pipe to resolve date issue.

When I served the application, I got this error on the console:

[image: date error]

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are only for display logic, and therefore cannot be used in situations like `ngModel`. Perform the logic in your TypeScript file to return the format you need.

Comment: - Can you show me an example? I've been on this issue for days

Answer (score 0):

Please use [ngModel]="form.loading_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'"  (ngModelChange)=" form.loading_date= $event"

Instead of two-way binding like below
     [(ngModel)]="form.loading_date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'"

Comment: I believe ngModel won't work with pipe, to display date use the value property with pipe directive and onblur you can write a function which can store updated value